# How to make a responsive button menu

Tags: html, css, button, menu, position

I have several pages with the following configuration:
a background-image(centered) and vertical menu (button) in a div.
=> https://ibb.co/3Cmf0dt

The div-menu, will be placed on the right but depending on a page to another, once centered, once a little higher.

I would like to have your help for the CSS of the div-menu.
How is it positioned so that it is reduced (with the buttons) and always remains in the same place compared to the background image ?

Here is my code(but button don't reduce and div possition refer to page and not image-background):

=> https://ibb.co/9cQL1yD

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!

Comment: Please don't add your code as a image that way we can't copy and debug it. Try to make a snippit

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to add in the body mesage :-(

But I don't search how to do a menubar but a div with 3 vertical button who are responssive and positionning in a special place in the page

Answer (score 0):

Open this in a tab then resize your window.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">&times;</i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's the link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav